# Cascading parameters in Crystal Reports that are NOT based on report data

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Can you have cascading parameters / dynamic parameters that are NOT based on data?  My report is basically on demand printing where there are 6 categories of reports and each report can have from 3 - 8 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate command and use it as a datasource for your parameters values.

Answer (score -1):

You want the user to enter or select from a static list of values in one parameter and that choice should limit the values shown by a dynamic parameter?
That can't be done in Crystal alone but there is at least one 3rd-party viewer that offers that functionality.
See list of 3rd-party viewers [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers).